# How do I access recipients for an Outlook mail message when using GetTable?

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

For performance, I am enumerating an Outlook mail folder using GetTable().  This gives me a collection of Row objects I can enumerate to get specific properties in the given folder.  I can control the coluumns in my result using the Columns collection of the Table before I begin enumerating.  Overall, this works fine.  However, I can't figure out how to access any of the multi-values properties.  Specifically, the I can't get any values back for the recipients of the message.

I have added the recipients column to the desired set of columns, but it always comes back null.  I have inspected the associated messages with MFCMAPI and clearly there are recipients :-)

The [documentation for GetTable says that certain types of columns are only partially supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147580(v=office.12).aspx).  It does talk about Recipients:

> Properties returning an object, such as Attachments, Parent, Recipients, 
>   RecurrencePattern, and UserProperties.

But it specifically says:

> Not supported if property is referenced by its explicit built-in name; 
>   supported if property is referenced by its namespace.

I am referencing the property (using Columns.Add) using its namespace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E12000D.  However, the value always comes back null.

Something is wrong!  Can anybody provide me with an example of enumerating through recipients using the recipients property (PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS) with GetTable?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible.  See discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/dd2925c9-1128-461b-a291-8420597f4619